# could not find cursor over collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, cursor

I am working around `MongoDB` and recently facing a bug/issue with the cursor. Default cursor time is 10 minutes I suppose and after which if you try to iterate cursor it would give an exception `cursor not found`.

But I am having this issue even for 4 minutes (sometimes). According to MongoDB documentation, If the time interval between iteratations is greater/equal to 10 minutes there would be timeout error, but this is happening for less then 10 minutes.

Comment: "Default cursor time is 10 minutes I suppose": well you shouldn't suppose and check for yourself. Maybe the default is below 4 minutes... Or if you're sure, then post the code you used to check the default time.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I have checked here for timeout.. 
Link: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/

And i am sure i have not changed the default time out.
Like i said "sometimes" which obviously states that if cursor timeout would be below 4, it would always give the "cursor timeout exception" and not "sometimes". And this also implies that, it works for 10 minutes as well the other times.